# How to make MultiPan Fragment layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new in android developing so i don't know how to make layout page like below picture. Please help me to create multipan framgment layout

[image]

Comment: u can use drawer concept to build like this also OR Sliding Window Concept too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use MultiPan Fragment in this case. you can read about the same from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) In each fragment you will need to use different Listview/recyclerView as per your logic and interact with them at runtime.

Comment: can to give me some link of tutorials i haven't find ryt tuorial

Comment: See if this gonna help you out. http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-fragments-example-ui-multi-pane.html

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh Patadiya You are a great  android developer.

Comment: Happy to help you Anand :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into RecyclerView or listviews. You can also make your own custom view inside the a row view.